# Implication from an equality in terms of expectations for uniqueness proof

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

I have shown that a solution to a nonlinear equation exists, and I am trying to show it is unique. Let *Y* > 0 be a continuous random variable, and $a_1$, $a_2$ real parameters. I have determined that if

$${E(Y^{a_1+1})\over E(Y^{a_1})}={E(Y^{a_2+1})\over E(Y^{a_2})}\Rightarrow a_1=a_2$$

then the solution is unique. But I have not been able to make much progress in establishing whether the implication is correct, or whether it would be correct under some weak assumptions about *Y* (beyond finite mean and variance). If that helps, *Y* may be assumed to have finite support and the parameters may be assumed to be positive.

Any comment or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the distribution of $Y$ is continuous the distribution of $Y$ is not degenerate (i.e., not a point mass) and the function $f:a\mapsto \log EY^a$ is strictly convex, so $g(a):=f(a+1)-f(a)$ is strictly increasing so $g(a_1)=g(a_2)$ implies  $a_1=a_2$.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Given g(a) strictly increasing, it would seem there cannot be two different values of a , $a_1$ and $a_2$, that make  g($a_1$) = g($a_2$) . Did you mean g($a_1$) = g($a_2$) implies  $a_1$ = $a_2$ ?

Comment: Good catch: yes, a typo; head-slap to me. As you said, I meant $g(a_1)=g(a_2)$ implies $a_1=a_2$.